# \textbeta and \textmu defined in the beamer class

Tags: beamer, macros, greek

I really like using UTF-8 greek letters in my latex code source and I use utf8x to convert them into `\textalpha` commands and then I define the `\textalpha` commands in a separate file where I write this, for each greek letter:

```
\newcommand{\textalpha}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}
```

And can even afford the luxury to use `\varepsilon` and `\varphi`.

This is actually the least intrusive and the most compatible way I found of doing this. (Well actually a little sed-parser was a lot more versatile and efficient because I knew what was going on but that's a very intrusive method)

Sadly this ... does not work with beamer because it seems to already have defined `\textbeta` and `\textmu`. Yes, only them. I don't know why.

Here is how to reproduce this. (This compiles. If you uncomment anything it won't compile)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\textalpha}{\alpha}
%\newcommand{\textbeta}{\beta}
%\newcommand{\textmu}{\mu}
\begin{document}
  $α$
  % $β$
  % $μ$
\end{document}
```

Does somebody know why? And also, how to overcome this? If I use `\renewcommand` it works in beamer files but it won't work in non-beamer files. Maybe there is a `\forcerenewcommand` that I don't know about?

Comment: maybe you want to use `\providecommand` which does nothing, if the command already exist and does a `\newcommand` otherwise.

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld thank you I will definitely use this as a workaround (with renewcommand).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why `beamer` has a `\textbeta`. Maybe someone else can give that answer.

There of course are ways to overwrite an existing macro.

For example you can use `\def` to overwrite any existing macro definition. This lacks `\newcommand`'s syntax, though. So you could instead define a new command that checks if the command already exists and depending on the ckeck either invokes `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
% check if csname is defined
\newcommand*\checkfor[1]{%
  \ifx#1\AMostCertainlyUndefinedCommand
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
% define in any case
\newcommand*\forcenewcommand[1]{%
  \checkfor{#1}{\newcommand{#1}}{%
    \GenericWarning{}{Warning: redefining \string#1}{}%
    \renewcommand{#1}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\textalpha}{\alpha}
% this works, of course:
\def\textbeta{\beta}
% as will the new definition command:
\forcenewcommand{\textmu}{\mu}

% for demonstration purposes only:
\forcenewcommand\textbf[1]{(#1)}

\begin{document}
  $α$
  $β$
  $μ$
  \textbf{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is using `\checkfor` any better than doing `\providecommand{\textbeta}{DEBUG-providecommand} \renewcommand{\textbeta}{\beta}`? (Apart from the warning)

Comment: @jmad I woudn't think so. Except less typing for you maybe if you don't have to define each command twice...